# Get a sibling from given node

Tags: c#, .net, xml, siblings

I have this XML file:

```
 <material>
   <item>
      <name>theName1</name>
      <val1>1.1</val1>
      <val2>2.5</val2>
      <val3>5.2</val3>
   </item>
   <item>
      <name>theName2</name>
      <val1>2.1</val1>
      <val2>3.5</val2>
      <val3>6.2</val3>
   </item>
 </material>
```

Ok, now I have 1 thing: the value of one the the item > name nodes (for example: theName2)
knowing this I need to select its siblings (val1, val2...)

Any ideas on how to go about this?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) Willing to share some code with us so that we could have a starting discussion point? Right now your question seems more like: *here are the specs, gimme the codez*.

Comment: I have this:

XmlDocument myXML = new XmlDocument();
myXML.Load("file.xml");
var nodes = myXML.SelectSingleNode("descendant:material[item/name=''theName1]");

Here's where I'm getting lost, I think it's selecting the right node, but I'm not sure how to get the siblings

Comment: It's not clear what you try to archive, see my answer. I'll update it if you add more details

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After Loading your xml into an XmlDocument, do:

```
document.SelectSingleNode("/material/item[val1='2']/name").InnerText
```

Is this what you need..?

Comment: What do you mean by val1='2'  ?

Comment: document.SelectSingleNode("/node1/innernode[input-node='value']/requiredNode").InnerText

Comment: Perfect!, that's all I needed

Answer (score 1):

A little bit  XPath + Linq may help

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml); //OR XDocument.Load(filename);
string xpath = String.Format("//item[name[text()='{0}']]","theName2");

var dict = xDoc.XPathSelectElement(xpath).Descendants()
            .Where(d=>d.Name.LocalName!="name")
            .ToDictionary(x=>x.Name.LocalName,x=>(decimal)x);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("file.xml");
IEnumerable<double> values =
    xdoc.Descendants("item")
        .Where(i => (string)i.Element("name") == "theName2") // select item
        .Select(i => i.Element("name")) // select name node 
        .SelectMany(e => e.ElementsAfterSelf()) // take siblings
        .Select(v => (double)v); // convert all value nodes to double
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var doc = XDocument.Parse(Xml); //create XDocument from string
    var items = doc.Descendants("item"); //select all 'item' elements
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        var childs = item.Elements().Skip(1); //skip <name> element
        foreach (var child in childs)
            Console.WriteLine(child); // val1, val2, val3, etc
    }
```

To select all "name" elements:

```
    var names = doc.Descendants("name");
    foreach (var name in names)
        Console.WriteLine(name);
```